# How-to load a dynamically appended script that won't load?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Dynamically appended script never loads:

```
const nodeTemplate = document.importNode(template.content, true)
const script = nodeTemplate.firstElementChild

script.removeAttribute('async')
script.setAttribute('defer', 'defer')
document.body.appendChild(nodeTemplate)
```

Any idea why? Is there a way to force it to load?

I've looked around at diverse solutions here and elsewhere and none seem to work as of now.

It works fine if it happens at page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check whether it's loaded or not, if not, better to remove completely that script from the DOM, and then create new `script` tag.

And then try something like this, it's common pattern to inject script widgets:

```
// 1. remove your old script
    
      // 2. create new
      (function(){
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = false;
            s.defer = true;
            s.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"; 
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
        })();
```

Comment: I was trying to find another way, but I'll implement it that way because it works and nothing else seems to, thank you.